# Add more font names in the Dnn Site in edit content

Tags: javascript, css, .net, fonts, dotnetnuke

Can some one help me on how to add more font names in the drop down list as of now we have only 9 i want to add one more font of my own and use it. I am currently using the fckeditor the dnn site.

I tried installing the font i need on my local machine and then added it on the fckconfig.js file, reset iis, clear browser cache and it did not work, Any other guidance will be helpful.

Thank You

Comment: The fonts used in HTML Module in DNN 7 are Arial,Courier New, Garamond, Georgia, MS Sans Serif Segoe UI, Tahoma, Times New Roman, Verdana. and I want to use the other fonts. so how to add other fonts to these fonts to allow clients to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your DNN version? FckEditor became obsolete in 2010, see http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/fckeditor-provider.

But there are more than 1 fckconfig.js files to be found in the DNN installation. Edit the config files in the following folders and see if it works.

```
\Providers\HtmlEditorProviders\Fck\Custom

\Providers\HtmlEditorProviders\Fck\fckeditor\editor\_source\internals

\Providers\HtmlEditorProviders\Fck\fckeditor
```

UPDATE: You need to edit the config file in the "Custom" folder. It worked here on a DNN test installation.

```
FCKConfig.FontNames = 'Test Font;Arial;Comic Sans MS;Courier New;Tahoma;Times New Roman;Verdana' ;
```

Comment: I am using DNN Version  07.02.01 and i have already made my changes in two of these config files i could not see them                                                                                               \Providers\HtmlEditorProviders\Fck\Custom                           \Providers\HtmlEditorProviders\Fck\fckeditor

Comment: So what is best recommended now?

Comment: Are there any more config files? Maybe your installation has one at a different location. Are you sure you are using the Fckeditor and not the Ckeditor? I could not find a standalone installation of Fckeditor for DNN 7 to test. It could be that it is still there when you upgraded from 5 to 6 to 7 for example but then I'm not able to test that specific scenario.

Comment: Editor settings can also be stored at the portal and even module level. The settings for a specific module are stored in the TabModuleSettings table in the database. At portal level it is stored in the HostSettings table like this: `DNNFCKP#xx#yy` (xx is the Portal ID and yy the setting name). Maybe there were settings stored like this in the past and they will overwrite any settings from the config file. If this doesn't work then I'm out of ideas.